# Error: Input type must be defined in inputTypes jovo-framework

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, jovo-framework

[Follow Docs](https://www.jovo.tech/docs/.model#values)
I tried to make Custom Entities (Developer Entities) as following lines:

`en-US.json`:

```
{
        "name": "TopicChooseIntent",
        "phrases": [
            "play {topic} chart",
            "{topic} music",
            "play {topic} music",
            "what's {topic} today",
            "what {topic} today"
        ],
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "topic",
                "type": {
                    "dialogflow": "@sys.any"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "city",
                "type": "@dev-city"
            }
        ],
        "inputTypes": [
            {
                "name": "@dev-city",
                "dialogflow": {
                    "automatedExpansion": true
                },
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": "Berlin"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "New York",
                        "synonyms": [
                            "New York City"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

,
"dialogflow": {
    "intents": [
        {
            "name": "Default Fallback Intent",
            "auto": true,
            "webhookUsed": true,
            "fallbackIntent": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Default Welcome Intent",
            "auto": true,
            "webhookUsed": true,
            "events": [
                {
                    "name": "WELCOME"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`app.js`

```
app.setHandler({
    'TopicChooseIntent': function (topic) {
    }
})
```

And it got below error when I want to build via command line `jovo build` :

```
❯ Updating /platforms/googleAction/dialogflow
 ✔ Updating Dialogflow Agent
   ✔ agent.json
   ✔ package.json
 ❯ Updating Dialogflow Language Model based on Jovo Language Model in /models
   ✖ en-US
     -> Input type "@dev-city" must be defined in inputTypes
{ Error: Input type "@dev-city" must be defined in inputTypes
at DialogFlowAgent.transform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jovo-cli/helper/dialogFlowAgent.js:381:35)
at Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jovo-cli/helper/dialogflowUtil.js:230:21)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Object.buildLanguageModelDialogFlow (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jovo-cli/helper/dialogflowUtil.js:225:16)
at Task.task (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jovo-cli/commands/tasks.js:332:38)
at Promise.resolve.then.then.skipped (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jovo-cli/node_modules/listr/lib/task.js:168:30)
 context:
 { locales: [ 'en-US' ],
 type: [ 'googleAction' ],
 projectId: undefined,
 endpoint: 'jovo-webhook',
 target: 'all',
 src: '/Users/folder/Desktop/GoogleHome/',
 stage: '',
 askProfile: 'default' } }
```

Actually, I don't know how to make it correctly,

Please help me,

Really thanks.

p/s :

- I totally understand Developer Entities since I able to make Custom Entities (Developer Entities) on DialogFlow easily. Please see image as sample

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

- If not use this Developer Entities, I able to run command line : 
  `jovo build` `jovo deploy --project-id ...` `jovo run`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I able to avoid this issue.

I know that this `json` file I define incorrectly.

So I need modify to get correct result as below codes :

`en-US.json`

```
"name": "TopicChooseIntent",
        "phrases": [
            "play {topic} chart",
            "{topic} music",
            "play {dev-city} music",
            "choose {dev-city} music",
            "what's {topic} today",
            "what {topic} today"
        ],
"inputs": [
        {
            "name": "topic",
            "type": {
                "dialogflow": "@sys.any"
            }
        }
    ],
"inputTypes": [
        {
            "name": "@dev-city",
            "dialogflow": {
                "automatedExpansion": true
            },
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": "Berlin"
                },
                {
                    "value": "New York",
                    "synonyms": [
                        "New York City"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

`en-US.json`

```
"dialogflow": {
    "intents": [
        {
            "name": "Default Fallback Intent",
            "auto": true,
            "webhookUsed": true,
            "fallbackIntent": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Default Welcome Intent",
            "auto": true,
            "webhookUsed": true,
            "events": [
                {
                    "name": "WELCOME"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "entities": [
        {
            "name": "dev-city",
            "isOverridable": false,
            "isEnum": false,
            "automatedExpansion": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the name. The [Dialogflow Docs for Developer Entities](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/developer-entities) states that they should "*start with a letter and can contain the following: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _ (underscore), - (dash)*".

Have you tried removing the `@` and just use `dev-city` as entity name?

Comment: No, i changed from `@dev-city` to `devcity` still got same error : `Error: Input type "devcity" must be defined in inputTypes`. 

Do I need to define Entities name in the other place?

p/s: I updated question for you to see more info.

Comment: Quick question: Could you run your Jovo model en-US.json file through a JSON validator like https://jsonlint.com/ to see if there's anything wrong with the format?

Comment: Yes, totally valid json. I updated question for you to see ^^ Looks like you never get this issue? ^^ Could you give me correct sample for this issue? And find the solution for this?